# What does EntityManager::getDelegate return?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am using JBoss 7 with the default Hibernate JPA engine in an EJB3 / JSF project.

The [javadoc on EntityManager::getDelegate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) reads: "Return the underlying provider object for the EntityManager, if available.".

Out of curiosity I tried the following code:

```
@Stateless
public class AFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="foo")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<A> findAll() {
         l.info("underlying entity manager is: "+em.getDelegate().getClass().getSimpleName());
         ...
    }
```

The output however indicates the classname as: **org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl** which, according to [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.html) is a Session implementation.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPA is just a specification for ORM; there are some implementations for this specification/API the most known being Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA.

This means that the `EntityManager` is just an adapter to a class from the implementation library. In your case it is `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` since you use Hibernate as a JPA implementation - **this is the class that manages the code you give to the `EntityManager`**.

Comment: Yeap, the JBoss Hibernate reference (http://tinyurl.com/7mdpjbv) reads "This interface (i.e. the EntityManager) is similar to the Session in Hibernate". It just struck me as weird that it should be named 'session'.

Comment: Just an update: in newer versions of Hibernate the "getDelegate()" method now returns an "org.hibernate.Session" object.