# java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy379 cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy379 cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy379 and org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I am getting this exception when I am trying to convert it in spring data jpa custom repository.

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlBuffer.toString());
    // BELOW LINES WILL GIVE US THE MAP OF PROPERTIES
    org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl hibernateQuery = ((org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl) q);
    hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

    return q.getResultList();
```

I am getting exception at:
org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl hibernateQuery = ((org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl) q);

Answer (score 0):

The `entityManager.createNativeQuery` is not required to return the underlying provider's implementation of the `Query` interface - such as [`NativeQueryImpl`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/internal/NativeQueryImpl.html) - directly.

The [EntityManager#getDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434469/what-does-entitymanagergetdelegate-return) returns the Hibernate [session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html), which in turn can be used to [create the native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782717/execute-native-sql-with-hibernate) from SQL string.  That would IMHO come close to getting hands on the [`NativeQueryImpl`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/internal/NativeQueryImpl.html) class. But I would not rely on that either - the Hibernate `Session` is expected to return [NativeQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/NativeQuery.html) instance. This might be the `org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl` today and something very different tomorrow.

I personally would prefer to work with [NamedNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) instead. And as general principle, always work only with declared interfaces and never cast to `Impl` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you are probably not in a @Transaction.